# AngularJS variable from first response not passed to second request?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as backend, I need to send post twice, first for `_User` class and `customer` class. `Customer` class have `user_id` field which pointer to `_User.objectId`.

The scenario is I send post to `_User` get the objectId, and send post to `customer` which contain `_User` objectId.

Here is my code

```
    $http.post('http://128.199.249.xxx:1337/parse/users', data, configRegister).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);  
    $scope.userObjectId = response.data.objectId;
    console.log($scope.userObjectId); //succes print objectId
}, function (error) {
    alert(error.data.error);
});


var dataProfileCustomer = {
    user_id : {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "_User",
        objectId: $scope.userObjectId //this part is not exist when I check in post request
    },
    family_name: $scope.customer.family_name,
    family_phone: $scope.customer.family_phone,
    family_address: $scope.customer.family_address
};

$http.post('http://128.199.249.xxx:1337/parse/classes/customer', dataProfileCustomer, configRegister).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data); 
}, function (error) {
    alert(error.data.error);
});
```

The above code result successfully insert in 2 class, `customer.user_id` is undefined.

Is something missing or wrong with my code?

Comment: You have to write second http.post request code inside the success response of first http.post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write second http.post request code inside the success response of first http.post request.

```
$http.post('http://128.199.249.xxx:1337/parse/users', data, configRegister).then(
function (response) {
    console.log(response);  
    $scope.userObjectId = response.data.objectId;
    console.log($scope.userObjectId); //succes print objectId

    var dataProfileCustomer = {
        user_id : {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "_User",
            objectId: $scope.userObjectId //this part is not exist when I check in post request
        },
        family_name: $scope.customer.family_name,
        family_phone: $scope.customer.family_phone,
        family_address: $scope.customer.family_address
    };
    $http.post('http://128.199.249.xxx:1337/parse/classes/customer', dataProfileCustomer, configRegister).then(
    function (response) {
        console.log(response.data); 
    }, function (error) {
        alert(error.data.error);
    });


}, function (error) {
    alert(error.data.error);
});
```